# MacBook Air M1, I have a login screen but no account is showing although I have one

Tags: hard-drive, password, login, login-screen

I can’t login to my Mac. It gives me the login screen but doesn’t accept my email and password. Also, it’s not using my account nor logging in automatically with my Apple Watch. What can I do? It looks like my account was deleted. <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> don’t work at all for some reason.

How can I log in to my Mac?

Comment: Normally, you don’t use an email address for a username login.  Did you use your name or some other variant like first initial last name?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried every form of login I have ever used on Mac to be honest. It’s also reverted to the old factory shipped colours. I had It customised with my picture en background. That’s all gone now. It’s the generic screen now. Really weird.

Comment: Ooh and pressing ⬆️ doesn’t show anything. Normally you would see other users but it doesn’t.

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted.  Did you buy this Mac new or used?  Did you make Time Machine backups?

Comment: It’s bought new, almost a year old now thou. And yes I have backups. I can’t see if I’m downvoted or not(I think). I just need to use my Mac, could use the help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you confusing local Mac account with iCloud account by a chance? Because this doesn't seem to make any sense, since accounts on Mac are identified with **username** /password pair, not **email** /password

Comment: I’m trying to login to my Mac. My iCloud is fine. I used my email because I don’t know what the hell was going on. Normally I see my name and picture and I put in my password or my watch does it for me. When that didn’t happen I kinda flooded the zone with everything and the kitchen sink.

Comment: OMG it worked , thank you so much!!  @Allan

Comment: Don’t forget to mark your answer as “accepted” so folks know that the question has a working solution.  Again, glad you got it working!

Comment: Will do, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you forget your username, you can try your full name, first and last.  Also try with the middle initial or  middle name fully spelled out, if applicable.

This is what worked for me.